# Django form code is not working correctly on server [webfaction]

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class QuoteListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quote_sets = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,  
                    queryset=QuoteSet.objects.filter(is_public=True))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        creator = kwargs.pop('creator', None)
        super(QuoteListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instance.creator = creator
        if creator is None:
            del self.fields['is_public']
        else:
            self.fields['quote_sets'].queryset = QuoteSet.objects.get_list(user=creator)
```

My form code. I am changing quote_sets field's queryset depend on user signed in or not.

Is it working correctly on my localhost. But on server [webfaction] form is not passed to template.

Any ideas pls?

Comment: Have you restarted the server? On webfaction, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: is get_list() a custom manager class?

Comment: yeah. It is custom manager class. I always restart the server. I found the problem. On server when cyrillic data added to database, raises BadUnicodeData error. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, you definitely need to reboot the server, otherwise it won't reflect the changes in your code.

Navigate to your server, then type

```
apache2/bin/restart
```

Alternatively, what error message are you getting? Is it actually finding the template file? You can have a look at the error logs using tail ~/logs/user/*

Comment: I restarted server and it didn't report any error on log. Also it didn't raise Exception.